# How can I implement HTML inside a label with CSS formatting?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Recently I asked a question about implementing HTML into a label and was given a very good answer:

[Is there any way I can add HTML into a Xamarin.Forms page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46816351/is-there-any-way-i-can-add-html-into-a-xamarin-forms-page)

However I would like to also have some common CSS for the HTML and also have the ability to add this into the back end C# code rather than XAML. Can anyone give me suggestions on how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your answer is in that linked question : "*If you want full-blown html support, then Xamarin forms WebView would be way to go*".

Adding CSS is probably easiest to achieve by using `WebView`.

Comment: I think you are right but I did try WebView and I was unable to get anything to display.  I opened another question on this showing what I had tried.  Hopefully someone can help there.